# How to get only the value from an array of objects in javascript with out mention it's key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of object like:

```
var customerArr = [
                  {
                  name:'Tarmizi',
                  address: 'Bintaro'
                  },
                  {
                  name:'Imam',
                  address: 'Pejaten'
                  },
                  {
                  name:'gugi',
                  address: 'Depok'
                  },
                  {
                  name:'een',
                  address: 'Bintaro'
                  }
            ];
```

The result I want to is:

```
Tarmizi
Imam
gugi
een
```

I can get the result like above with:

```
for(customer in customerArr){
    console.log(customerArr[customer].name);    
}
```

But in my case the object of array I get from json array by uploading excel file with header has space.

So, I need to get the value of array with out mention of it's key.

```
for(customer in customerArr){
   console.log(customerArr[customer].name <-- with out .name);    
}
```

Thank a lot before

Comment: Why again can't you use .name? is it instead `" name"`? Why can't you use that instead in bracket notation just like you did for `customer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `customerArray[key]` to extract the value of a given property in an object. Since `key` will be a string, it doesn't really matter if there are spaces inside it.

So, using the array you provided in the question:

```
var values = new Array;
customerArray.forEach((customer) => {
  if(costumer['name']) values.push(customer['name']);
  return;
}
```

With this code, values will be equal to your array of names. Notice that the string 'name' is pulled out from your array example, but can be any string, containing spaces too. More than that, you don't have to assume that your objects key-value pairs are sorted correctly.

**UPDATED** after @squint comment

Comment: Your code relies on knowing the property name, which is what the OP is trying to avoid. Either way, why would you loop the `Object.keys()` if you already know the name?

Comment: If I understood well the question, he want to avoid to name the property because it can contain spaces, not because he don't know about it. Looping the keys is pointless, you're right, I'll update the answer.

Comment: If the space is the actual reason, then the OP really has no problem except for knowing how to access properties correctly in that situation. You'll also want to change `values.slice.call(...`. Not sure what you were going for there.

Comment: Quoting the question: "But in my case the object of array I get from json array by uploading excel file with header has space. So, I need to get the value of array with out mention of it's key."

Comment: Thanks you Mr. Lucas it's save my time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a property name that you have in a variable by enclosing it in square brackets:

```
var propertyName = 'name';  // Property name from header array
var customerArr = [
              {
              name:'Tarmizi',
              address: 'Bintaro'
              },
              {
              name:'Imam',
              address: 'Pejaten'
              },
              {
              name:'gugi',
              address: 'Depok'
              },
              {
              name:'een',
              address: 'Bintaro'
              }
        ];
for(customer in customerArr){
  console.log(customerArr[customer][propertyName]);
}
```

Comment: You're using a known name. The OP is trying to do this without knowing the name.

Comment: I'm using a known name but I think the OP is indicating the name is available from a header row "uploading Excel file with has space" so likely in a variable in some structure that simply using bracket notation on would give the desired result for.  Anyway question is on hold to clear up the actual meaning which is probably sensible as everything so far is guess work